# Writer in a txt file using Spring Batch

Tags: xml, spring-batch

How to organize writer in a txt file using Spring Batch?

Spring Batch has:

- FlatFIleItemWriter
- StaxEventItemWriter
- StoredProcedureItemWriter
- JDBCPagingItemWriter
- MongoItemWriter

but which can I use to write data to txt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A text file is a flat file, so you can use the `FlatFileItemWriter`. You can implement the `LineAggregator` interface to write any type of structured or unstructured text. You can find an example in this section: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#SimplifiedFileWritingExample